# Mapbox how to show map labels to the language used locally for the place, and the map labels in English in the rest of map

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

**I want to show the map labels in the language used locally for the place,
and the map labels in English in the rest of world.**

I know this is the normal behaviour for Mapbox [available language](https://www.mapbox.com/help/change-language/#languages-available) 
for example : in Germany labels are shown in German, and in the rest of map, if there is no translation - the language is English

**But**
If I'm dealing with non-available language, and I set the label language to "name" (==locale) the labels in my place is displayed in the locale but in the rest of map -every place with its locale and not in English

I've search a lot but didn't find any solution

thank you for giving your time

Comment: Are you getting map labels from the server, as user input or from strings.xml?

Comment: @TheKarlo95 openStreets (through mapBox)